# Cant understand why this doesn't print to the text file

Tags: java, arrays, text-files, jtextfield, printwriter

Im coding a hotel reservation program and im using a GUI to input the Guests info into TextFields. I have an array where these input values should go straight to (maybe thats my problem, but donno how to fix it). After this I want the values in the Array to print to the text file I had created. Heres my code:

```
Guests[] GArr = new Guests[1000];
   public static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
   public int cnt = 1;
   int count = 0;
   String Firstname ;
   String Lastname;
   String Country ;
   String IDtype;
   String PassportNo ;
   String IDNo ;
   String Addr1;
   String Addr2 ;
   int AreaCode ;
   String TelNo ;
   String CellNo ;
   String Email ;
```

First I have declared these variables as global (these variables are already in my object class `Guests`) i put them again in my JFrame class called `Home`. After that I have made these variables take the value of the `TextFields` that have text input into them. This is within a method that checks to see if the fields are blank:

```
public Collection<String> getNonBlankFields()  {
    this.Firstname = NameF.getText();
    this.Lastname = NameL.getText();
    this.Country = Countr.getText();
   this.IDtype = IDTy.getText();
    this.PassportNo = PassNo.getText();
    this.IDNo = IDNumber.getText();
    this.Addr1 = Add1.getText();
    this.Addr2 = Add2.getText();
    int AreaCode = Integer.parseInt(Area.getText());
    this.TelNo = Tel.getText();
    this.CellNo = Cell.getText();
    this.Email = Em.getText();

    this.nonBlankFields = new ArrayList<String>();
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.Firstname);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.Lastname);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.Country);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.IDtype);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.PassportNo);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.IDNo);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.Addr1);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.Addr2);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.TelNo);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.CellNo);
    this.nonBlankFields.add(this.Email);
    System.out.println(this.nonBlankFields);
    return this.nonBlankFields;
}
```

Last thing is the printing to the file (this is my major problem) ive tried so many things to fix this but it surpasses this code and goes straight to the catch:

```
     File GFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Gordy\\Dropbox\\IT\\Hotel Reservation\\Hotel\\src\\Reservation\\Guests.txt");
try {
            if (!GFile.exists()) {
                GFile.createNewFile();
            } 
                String delim = "#";
               String Firstname = NameF.getText();
                    StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(delim);
                    Firstname += stk.nextToken();
                    System.out.print("FName = " + Firstname);
                    Lastname += stk.nextToken();
                    System.out.print("LastName= " + Lastname);
                    Country += stk.nextToken();
                    System.out.print("Country= " + Country);
                    IDtype += stk.nextToken();
                    IDNo += stk.nextToken();
                    Addr1 += stk.nextToken();
                    Addr2 += stk.nextToken();
                    AreaCode += Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
                    TelNo += stk.nextToken();
                    CellNo += stk.nextToken();
                    Email += stk.nextToken();
                    GArr[count] = new Guests(Firstname, Lastname, Country, IDtype,  IDNo,Addr1,Addr2, AreaCode, TelNo, CellNo, Email);
                    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter (GFile,true));
                    pw.println(GArr[count]);
                    count++;
                    pw.close();
                    CheckIn.hide();
                    Home.this.setVisible(true);
            }
         catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("This did not work heres the error: " + e);
        }
```

would also love to use anything but `StringTokenizer` to print with `#` in between the data on 1 line.

this is the whole error:

```
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
at Reservation.Home.jButton8ActionPerformed(Home.java:1657)
at Reservation.Home.access$100(Home.java:29)
at Reservation.Home$2.actionPerformed(Home.java:269)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: what's in the exception?

Comment: You say it goes through to the `catch`. Can we get the error stack trace? `e.printStackTrace()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `stk.nextToken()` multiple times, but that object only holds a single "#". This means that you can only call `nextToken()` on it once. Also `Integer.parseInt("#")` probably throws an exception. I would suggest doing something like this :

Don't add "#" to anything and instead for your `toString()` method in `Guests` do something like

```
public String toString() {
    return Firstname + "#" + Lastname + "#" + ... + "#" + Email;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly the smallest mistake by me made this whole thing not work (How stupid do I get). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// instantiate array after all vars in it have been instantiated
String[] guests = {Firstname, Lastname, Country, IDtype,  IDNo,Addr1,Addr2, AreaCode, TelNo, CellNo, Email};

int ct=0;
for(StringTokenizer stk; stk.hasMoreElements() ;){
guests[ct]+=stk.nextToken();
ct+=1;
}
```

Stringtokenizer is an "enumeration" object, it must be iterated so it requires a "boolean test" "hasMoreElements()".

Answer (score 0):

You're using the StringTokenizer in a wrong way.
It probably throws an exception because there are no more tokens available.

You can use a List instead of a big array.

Here is some of the refactored code to print into the file as 
Firstname#Lastname#Country#IDtype#IDNo#Addr1#Addr2#AreaCode#TelNo#CellNo#Email

First portion of your code:`Guests[] GArr = new Guests[1000];`

I Changed to:
`List<Guests> guestList = new ArrayList<>();`

Third portion of your code:

```
File GFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Gordy\\Dropbox\\IT\\HotelReservation\\Hotel\\src\\Reservation\\Guests.txt");
try {
    if (!GFile.exists()) {
        GFile.createNewFile();
    } 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder;
    appendData(sb,Firstname);
    appendData(sb,Lastname); 
    appendData(sb,Country); 
    appendData(sb,IDtype); 
    appendData(sb,PassportNo); 
    appendData(sb,IDNo); 
    appendData(sb,Addr1); 
    appendData(sb,Addr2); 
    appendData(sb,AreaCode); 
    appendData(sb,TelNo); 
    appendData(sb,Email,false); 

    guestList.add(new Guests(Firstname, Lastname, Country, IDtype,  IDNo,Addr1,Addr2, AreaCode, TelNo, CellNo, Email));

    PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter (GFile,true));
    pw.println(sb.toString());

    pw.close();
    CheckIn.hide();
    Home.this.setVisible(true);
}catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.print("This did not work heres the error: " + e);
}
```

Here the appendData part

```
private void appendData(StringBuilder sb,String data){
    appendData(sb,data,true);
 }

 private void appendData(StringBuilder sb,String data,boolean delim){
    sb.append(data);
    if(delim){
        sb.append(delim);
    }
 }
 private void appendDelim(StringBuilder sb){
    sb.append("#");
 }
```

I'm not sure why you keep an data structure of guests if you just output it to a text file.